Can we use the simple present tense to express a habit that starts just about 24 hours or less ago?
We often use the simple present tense for repeated events that starts quite awhile ago.
Say a graduate had his first job a month ago after graduating from university and started to go to work then.
Now, he can say "I go to work every day".
Say, yesterday afternoon Lana was ok but when went to bathroom a few times last night and this morning and afternoon too.
Can I say "Why do you go to bathroom often?" even though she just started having the problem 24 hours ago?
Other options:
"Why are you going to bathroom often?"
"Why have you gone to bathroom often?"
"Why have you been going to bathroom often?"
"Why did you go to bathroom often?" (Note: now she is still doing it, so this option might not be suitable)

He can say "Starting from next Monday, I go to work every day".

In Lana's case you could ask "Why have you started going to the bathroom so often?", acknowledging that this is a recent behavior change.

As a practical matter, Lana may or may not accept that this really is an established ongoing fact. "Why do you go to the bathroom often?" "I don't, it's only been for the last 24 hours" is a completely believable exchange. But so is "Why do you go to the bathroom often?" "I don't know, I'll call the doctor later". You and Lana can debate how long it has to go on for before it's "ongoing"! You'll get different answers for different activities, and I think it's more a question of medicine than of the meaning of the English simple present.

“Why are you going to the bathroom so often?” It's already been said a few times, but  if someone learns visually, bolding the key words helps.

I would say this is more of a discourse question than a strictly linguistic one. That is, it really depends on what you consider to constitute a regular recurrence or a habit. The English tense is capable of expressing a variety of types of regularity that may or may not meet a given person's definition.
In your first example, he could certainly say "I go to work every day" a month into the job. Even after a week, most people would probably accept that this is the pattern of his current life, whatever "current" means. After two or three days it would probably get some pushback. "You've only been working there for two days!"
In your second example, first note that all your variants should read "so often", not just "often", which is too vague to suggest anything meaningful for something as variable as how often a person goes to the bathroom. Now, if you know Lana well and know that this isn't her usual habit, you won't use the present simple. You'd use "have you been going so often", "did you go so often last night", or "are you going so often the past couple of days". But if you've never met Lana and assume that this is her regular frequency, you could use the simple past. Here the facts are more relevant than the grammar.
But even for a recently established habit, some contexts would licence the simple present. Suppose that you and a friend sign up for a day of crocheting teddy bears for a toy drive. Although you can both crochet, you haven't done this particular pattern. Your friend gets there at 9 a.m., but you can only join her after lunch, so she crochets all morning. When you join her, she shows you her process. "Here's how I do it," she says with her three hours of experience. "I take the needles like this, and first I make the head like this, and then I make a loop here..." She's very naturally using the simple present because she's established a regular routine through continual practice, even though the actual timeframe is very short.
(Note that she could also say, "Here's how I've been doing it. I've been taking the needles, making the head like this, and then making a loop here..." This would seem to invite your feedback and refinement of the process, whereas the simple present would communicate a successful process that you're invited to emulate.)

In the case of the teddy bears, where there's a repeated task, I think the number of repeats is usually more important than the length of time. If you've made two bears you're licensed to say "this is how I make bears" in the simple present. If you've made one I think the simple present is questionable. If you've made none, but are planning to, I think it's highly doubtful.

@SteveJessop I agree about the number of iterations. Probably both that and time are factors. If you made seven in a minute (somehow) it still sounds kind of presumptuous to me to use the simple present the next minute.

Language is expressive.  Speakers use it to communicate their experience and view of things to another person. There is no "minimum amount of time" rule in the grammar. It is a subjective thing, not an objective one.
A person visiting the urgent care clinic for a problem that manifested itself just the day before could say:

I am going to the bathroom a lot.

The speaker feels they have gone to the bathroom often enough to conclude it is an ongoing pattern that is out of the ordinary for them.
A person might call their primary care doctor and say:

I sneeze (or am sneezing) a few  times every 30 seconds. It started about 15 minutes ago.


Tips (I want to get them out of the way before discussing the simple present):

"Go to the bathroom", not "go to bathroom". "Go to bathroom" is incorrect.
I think a fluent speaker would say "Do you go to the bathroom often?", and would say "Why do you go to the bathroom so often?", but would not usually say, "Why do you go to the bathroom often?". I don't know if there's a technical term in grammar or linguistics for the near-requirement to qualify "often" in that question. It might be because "often" is a scale. For the first question you can ask them to turn that scale into a binary "often" / "not often", but perhaps for the second question it makes more sense to ask "why" that position on the scale. Qualifying "often" does that.

For the simple present:
For your 24-hour medical example, I would use "Why are you going to the bathroom so often?" over "Why do you go to the bathroom so often?". Not because one is wrong, but because we assume (hope) that new medical conditions are temporary. The simple present expresses that we're ignoring when it started and when it might end. That's not quite appropriate for a 24-hour medical condition. "Why do you go to the bathroom so often" sounds more like what you'd ask someone who has been to the doctor, had their prognosis, and it's regular bathroom visits for the foreseeable future.
For your first example, yes, he can say "I go to work every day" as soon as it's established. For clarity, since this is news, he might say "Since last month, I go to work every day", or something like that, but that is to add more information, not because it's wrong without. If someone asked him to fill in a form, "Do you go to work every day?", then the correct answer is "yes"[*]. In fact it's unambiguously "yes" as soon as he starts the job: day 1 or 2.
You haven't asked about this, but the simple present can also be used for past events. This is sometimes called the "historical present". It makes you sound like a history textbook (which is sometimes what you want) to say, "In 1066 William of Normandy invades England and becomes William I". It could also be used for the future when discussing your diary. For example, "On Friday I'm working all day, on Saturday I leave for France, on Tuesday I get back, so I can see you Wednesday". You don't need to say it that way, but if you see it then it does not necessarily mean this person goes to France every week.
Summary:
The simple present ignores when the action started or will end. So, use it when those things are not relevant or you want to ignore them. There is not a specific amount of time after which the simple present becomes correct: there may be an approximate amount of time after which it is appropriate to ignore that it's new (or that it will soon end). This depends on the context.
[*] ignoring weekends and vacations. But that's a difficulty with the meaning of "every day", not a difficulty with the meaning of the simple present.
